# how to use local fonts with styled components and react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components, storybook

I'm creating a component library using `Reactjs`, `TypeScript`, and `Styled- components` 
the thing is I know I could use `createglobalstyle` according to the docs but I don't have an app, it's just a single component (also using storybook) so I'm not sure if i'm missing something or how can i use font-face without the need to wrap my app using  `<GlobalStyle />`

I tried but it didn't work

```
export const fonts = {
    fontSource: './fonts/fontname.woff',
    fontFamily: 'fontname',
}
```

```
//component.tsx
import { fonts, GlobalStyle } from '../../theme'

export const Component = styled.div<MyComponent>`
    font-family: ${fonts.fontFamily};
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you can use the fonts, you will need to add them either using `@font-face` or by hosting your font.

This reference will help you https://scotch.io/@micwanyoike/how-to-add-fonts-to-a-react-project.

Once you have done that, you can refer to your font in your css by the `font-family` value that you set while adding your font using `@font-face` or hosted font.

Comment: how can i add font-face without using `createglobalstyle`?

Comment: At this point it doesn't seem possible to do so, styled-components can create scoped keyframes (https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#keyframes) but not font-face (both @ rules). You can request a new feature on their Github.
Alternatively, you may reconsider why you want to scope your font-face, since it will be applied only where you use it in your component, unless you have two different fonts with the same name in your target environment.

Comment: @Habiba did you find a soultion to font face with createglobalstyle?